# How Do I Go About Scraping All URL's Within a <div and or <ul class? (Nesting / CSS Selectors) Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently doing research on just how good PGA Tour golfers are and what differentiates them from the majority of golfers. PGATour.com has a statistics page that shows every tournament with updated statistics all the way back to 1980. Metrics such as GIR, FIR, SS, UPD, etc.

I'd like all of these stats in a centralized dataset and I'm about 50% of the way done

This is the code I've tried thus far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

#Define the URL to extract from
url = "https://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RAPP_INQ.html"
page = requests.get(url)
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    df = print(link.get('href'))
```

You can run it yourself but it returns such a huge amount of data that isn't clean along with split URL's that I technically COULD append. The problem would be how to tell Python, "Hey just these URL's, append these to "https://www.PGATour.com"

A much more efficient way to simplify my code would be to simply nest the <div class that I want URL's from from the URL I want to scrape from.

Would I go into the source code for that or simply get all of the URL's from the inspect element page?

I'd rather go with the latter for the sake of efficiency but if you could point me in the right direction on how to learn how to do this, I'd be very grateful.

I've done tons of Google searches and have even watched Keith Galli's videos on webscraping but maybe I just need sleep after having this project on my mind for days. Just want to get it over with.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment - You could use `css selectors` as mentioned - Search for the `<div>` that contains your heading and choose the next sibling `<div>`:

```
soup.select('.header:-soup-contains("Greens in Regulation") + div ul li a[href]')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

#Define the URL to extract from
url = "https://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RAPP_INQ.html"
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

[
    {'link':'https://www.PGATour.com'+a.get('href'),
     'categorie':a.find_previous('h3').text
     } 
    
    for a in soup.select('.header:-soup-contains("Greens in Regulation") + div ul li a[href]')
]
```

or more generic to get all the links from the section categoriezed, so you could filter you data in dataframe:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RAPP_INQ.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

data = [
    {'link':'https://www.pgatour.com'+a.get('href'),
     'categorie':a.find_previous('h3').text
     } 
    for a in soup.select('.module-statistics-off-the-tee-table ul li a[href]')
]

pd.DataFrame(data)#to_excel('myfile.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That cleaned up the URL output issue! Only issue is that it does show URL's that I don't require but it is no worries!

For instace if you go to https://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RAPP_INQ.html
I'd like to be able to tell Python, "Get all of the URL's from the Greens In Regulation table in the <div class="table-content clearfix". or "Get all of the URL's within the <h3>Greens in Regulation <div. All of the <li URL's within the <ul>

Comment: HedgeHog, That did wonders for me! 

I feel like I sound like I want people to do the project for me but I promise that's not the case. After months of trying to learn how to code with REAL projects rather than the typical, "Let's get the prices for this AMZN product using bs4", this is my first one and perhaps I'm just getting cold feet.

That all said, would I be able to clean this data to where I can use pandas module to_excel into a df from the list?

Or simply make it to where its a series / list of URL's I can copy paste into Excel?

Comment: Simply  use the list of dicts  with `pd.DataFrame(data).to_excel('myfile.xlsx')` to get your result.

Comment: HedgeHog, that worked for what I explained! Thank you!

Can Python assign each of the links into specific dataframes by perhaps using pandas?

For instance for each url, pandas.read_html("each individual url gets a table")?

Comment: @CJT2013, if the response above solved your issue, do not forget to mark it as accepted, and also upvote it. If you have a different question, then post a different question.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire, I'll make another post. I tried clicking the upvote button as well as the check mark earlier and it didn't work but this time it worked!

I'll post a follow up question after I've exhausted every route possible to figure out the next part of the subject